# Modes have no effect unless I deactivate and activate again

Tags: org-mode, init-file, auto-complete-mode

I'm extremely new to emacs (started using it yesterday),
I use the latest version of emacs.

The problem is, The modes I have enabled such as `auto-complete-mode` and `org-bullets-mode` seem to be enabled at launch. But i don't see their effect on screen unless I turn them off and on again (I'm not sure if the tex global pdf mode has activated either).

Since, I'm a beginner . I'm pretty sure this is horrible code writing on my part. So, A bit of insight into what went wrong and few resources into how to set it up would be a lot more helpful than just correcting my code.

This is my `init.el`:

```el
;Installing Repos
(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(package-initialize)
; Use evil mode
(require 'evil)
(evil-mode t)

;For Tex
(require 'tex)
(TeX-global-PDF-mode t)
(latex-mode)
(setq auto-complete-mode t)
(auto-complete)

;For Org
(require 'org-bullets)
(org-mode)
(setq org-bullets-mode t)
(org-bullets-mode)
;Window Size
(if (window-system)
    (set-frame-size (selected-frame) 100 200)) 
    
   
(custom-set-variables
  ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
  '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (misterioso)))
  '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
)
```

### Edit:

Even simpler things like

```el
(set-cursor-color "#ffffff")
```

Isn't working on startup. What am I doing wrong? Is my installation botched?

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46081523/850781

Comment: I'm sorry. I have deleted the stackexchange version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some variables in Emacs are [buffer-local](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Locals.html#Locals). This means that when you set them they apply only to the current buffer. Many minor modes are buffer-local. So running `(org-bullets 1)` enables `org-bullets` only in the current buffer.

To enable `org-bullets` in every `org-mode` buffer we use a hook that runs every time you open a new `org-mode` buffer.

```el
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
   (defun org-bullets-mode-enable ()
      (org-bullets-mode 1)))
```

Some minor modes can be enabled globally, usually by calling a function like `(global-auto-complete-mode 1)` which will enable `auto-complete-mode` in all buffers.

The problem you are having with `set-cursor-color` is that the `misterioso` theme is overriding your settings. I suggest you [use `customize-face` to change your cursor color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24234743/2103258).

```el
(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(package-initialize)

; Use evil mode

(require 'evil)
(evil-mode t)

;For Tex

(require 'tex)
(TeX-global-PDF-mode t)
(global-auto-complete-mode 1)

;For Org

(require 'org-bullets)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
(defun org-bullets-mode-enable ()
    (org-bullets-mode 1)))
    
;Window Size

(if (window-system)
  (set-frame-size (selected-frame) 100 200))

(custom-set-variables
  ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.

  '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (misterioso)))
  '(inhibit-startup-screen t))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining the Buffer-local thing. I made it work using hooks. But never really understood until now.